# Unity top panel missing application options

Tags: unity, 14.04

After the upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04, I am missing application specific options (in Firefox's case: "File", "Edit", "View" etc) from the unity top bar and they are displayed within application itself (like in most Windows OS).

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings, then Appearance, then Behaviour. At the bottom there are options under "Show the menus for a window" and click on "in the menu bar"

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I can select that option and toggle it off or on, but I still don't see menubar items on the top panel.